# Derivative of ratio of exponential functions: $ \frac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{x_{i}^{k}}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}\right). $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, functional-inequalities

Suppose we have a row vector $$X = [x_1\; \cdots \; x_n],$$
where $x_i>0$ for all $i$.
I have the function
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{x_{i}^{k}}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}\right).\quad (1)
\end{equation}
**I'm trying to prove that (1) is negative for all $x_i\neq \max\{x_j\}$.** This seems somewhat intuitive to me. However, my attempts to `prove' it have not been successful.

The obvious approach is to use the quotient rule, i.e., 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{x_{i}^{k}}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}\right)&=\frac{x_{i}^{k}}{\left(\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}\right)^{2}}\sum_{j}\frac{dx_{j}^{k}}{dk}-\frac{dx_{i}^{k}}{dk}\frac{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}{\left(\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}\right)^{2}} ,
\end{align*}
which could be carried forward as follows
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{x_{i}^{k}}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}\right)&=\frac{x_{i}^{k}}{\left(\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}\right)^{2}}\sum_{j}\frac{dx_{j}^{k}}{dk}-\frac{dx_{i}^{k}}{dk}\frac{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}{\left(\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}\right)^{2}} \\
& =\frac{x_{i}^{k}}{\left(\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}\right)^{2}}\sum_{j}\frac{dx_{j}^{k}}{dk}-\frac{1}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}\frac{dx_{i}^{k}}{dk}\\
 & =\frac{1}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}\left(\frac{x_{i}^{k}\sum_{j}\frac{dx_{j}^{k}}{dk}}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}-\frac{dx_{i}^{k}}{dk}\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}\left(\frac{x_{i}^{k}\frac{d}{dk}\left(\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}\right)}{\sum_{j}x_{j}^{k}}-\frac{dx_{i}^{k}}{dk}\right).
\end{align*}

It's not clear to me whether this is the right track to be going down, or how the conclusion could be drawn from this. **Can anyone help?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $R=x_i^k\big/\sum_j x_j^k$ to be decreasing in $k$.  Look instead at $S=1/R$, which is given by $$S=\sum_j \left(\frac{x_j}{x_i}\right)^k.$$
This is manifestly a convex function of $k$, and if any of the ratios $x_j/x_i >1$, increasing for all $k$ sufficiently large.

Depending on whether $x_i$ is the largest, smallest, or neither, of the $x_j$, the graph of $k\mapsto S$ can look, qualitatively, like that of $\exp (-k)$, $\exp k$, or $\cosh k$.

So the answer depends in part on whether you suppose $k>0$ or not.

Comment: Ok, yes. This is a better way to look at the problem. I'm interested in the $k>0$ region

Comment: In which case the derivative of $S(k)$, with respect to $k$, at $k=0$ will be decisive.  If $\sum \log(x_j/x_i) \ge 0$, you are increasing on $k\ge0$. But if the sum comes out $<0$, you are decreasing and then increasing.